# Button Is Clicked but still 'Unable to locate element' error is thrown by Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to press the Confirm button of a website whose HTML is like this

```
<footer>
    <button class="button btn-default page-container__footer-button" data-testid="page-container-footer-cancel" role="button" tabindex="0">Reject</button>
    <button class="button btn-primary page-container__footer-button" data-testid="page-container-footer-next" role="button" tabindex="0">Confirm</button>
</footer>
```

I click the Confirm button with this code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[3]/footer/button[2]').click()
```

**As it should be, Confirm Button is clicked by Selenium but still error this error thrown and due to which program stops.**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[3]/footer/button[2]"}
```

I know I can use Except Statement but I don't want to use it and instead would like to fix the error.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You are using **absolute xpath** which could be **brittle in nature**, if `Confirm` text is **static text for the button**, you can use `text` itself to represent this in HTMLDOM.

```
//button[text()='Confirm']
```

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//button[text()='Confirm']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Confirm']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Confirm']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Confirm']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Confirm']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Note that, This is an assumption that **button** is not in `iframe/frame` or `shadow root`.

**Update :**

**to scroll till bottom :**

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
```

Comment: Sure please make sure that we have unique element in HTMLDOM, steps to check are written over there, if that works we can possibly construct a css selector or xpath using `data-testid="page-container-footer-next"`. Please check for iframe, frame, frameset, shadow root, or if it's a new tab or windows.

Comment: I tried all 4 of them but got the same error in all except 2nd one whose error was `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: Here is the image for finding unique entry : https://i.imgur.com/hgN7wcS.png

Comment: The element is in bottom of the page ? also did you check for iframe ? just scroll up and see if there's any iframe.

Comment: Yes.. it's in the bottom of the page.

Comment: if it's in bottom of the page you have to scroll till bottom, please use `driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")` to scroll till bottom then you should be able to click. Update above as well.

Comment: Tried scrolling as well but got same error : `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237626/discussion-between-rakesh-poddar-and-cruisepandey).